# Can I use the FB Access token to create a FB session in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, uiwebview, facebook-javascript-sdk

So, my app grabs the FB access token during the registration process. I store this in the backend.

My goal is to allow the user to send a [FB App request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) through a UIWebView without logging in to facebook again.

My desired user flow is --

1. User signs up for my iOS app using Facebook
2. I store the FB access token in my DB
3. Later, one of my new features opens up a UIWebView
4. The user clicks on an "Invite this person using Facebook" button (I have the FB_id of the invitee and access token of the inviter)
5. The app request is sent to the user

So, my questions are

1. Can I send an app request using only the access token(of inviter) and fb_id(of invitee)?
2. If I need to create a FB session in the UIWebView, can I do that with FB.init?
3. Is there any way to send this request without having the user login to facebook again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent lots of time looking at this issue and after much research, I learned that it's not possible to get the desired behaviors.

1. No, you need to have an active fb session cookie dropped on your domain.
2. No, you cannot.
3. No, the user will have to login to send the request from the webview.

As a workaround, we are going to try to use the iOS SDK and then have an internal url(deep link) that launches the invitation request dialog from the webview.